Impact of Input Capacitor on the Derivation of the Small-Signal Model of the Buck-Boost Converter
I have been studying the control methods of DC/DC power converters over the past couple of weeks and am confused on how the addition of an input capacitor affects the small-signal model of the buck-boost converter. I have been unable to find any information about this specific topic on the internet so I thought that I would give it a shot here. Thank you for your time.

If you talk about adding a front-end filter, e.g. affecting the source output impedance, then yes, there can be interaction. I looked into this subject in my APEC 2017 seminar. I did the analysis on the buck converter but you can do the same for the buck-boost also. Quite a long exercise if you include the filter ^_^ On the other hand, if you just add a capacitor across the (perfect) input source, it does nothing to the small-signal response.

Most of the small-signal analyses consider a perfect input source so that the voltage biasing the converter is constant and equal to zero volt in ac analysis. In reality, the source features an output impedance - let's assume it is resistive - and that is why you have to decouple the dc-dc converter input with a front-end capacitor. This capacitor also hosts a parasitic equivalent resistance, the ESR, which affects the voltage effectively applied at the dc-dc input.
There is an impact on the control-to-output transfer function and it has been studied by Dr. Vatché Vorpérian when he introduced the PWM switch model in his IEEE paper, Simplified Analysis of PWM Converters Using Model of the PWM Switch:

This impact is modeled through an extra resistance \$r_e\$ added in series with the PWM switch model. Its presence impacts the quality factor \$Q\$ of the denominator in a CCM boost or buck-boost converter, actually damping the control-to-output transfer function. We can show this effect with the SIMPLIS simulation of a -12-V CCM buck-boost converter:

These are subtle effects, rarely included in ac analyses but they do exist. If you want to see the PWM switch model in action, my 2021 book goes deep into the small-signal analysis of many switching converters.

If your model has the supply as a voltage source the addition of the capacitor does nothing.  if you model is more realistic, the capacitor makes the supply more like a voltage source.
